# RDF validation keep giving error?

Tags: rdf

I keep getting this error whenever I tried to validate the rdf file in the following location

[the rdf file](http://awmarmo.net46.net/svu.rdf)

whats wrong with it ? please help .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a valid RDF/XML file. Every line in this file starts with a line number. This is probably because you copy-pasted it from somewhere. These line numbers are not allowed in RDF/XML and you have to get rid of them.

There might still be another problem that causes the encoding/UTF-8 error. This usually happens when you have special characters in the file and don't save it using UTF-8 encoding. But fix the error with the line numbers first and then this will be clearer.

Another unrelated problem: In `xmlns:u="http://awmarmo.net46.net/Schema.rdf"` there's a hash “`#`” missing at the end of the URL. Namespace URIs in RDF basically always end either in a slash “`/`” or hash “`#`”. If you forget them, things break.

Comment: Didnt work , I added the encoding <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> but still getting error

Comment: The file looks correct to me now, and I tried to load it with various RDF tools and it all works. Might be something wrong with the RDF validator.